# MFC create Modeless dialog that does not lose focus

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to create a dialog in MFC that, once it shows up, it can't lose focus.
This is for blocking the user access to the main SDI window, while it is processing data. The flow is something similar to:

1. User triggers process
2. Application shows the dialog
3. Application starts the process function

I can't do this with a Modal dialog, because the `DoModal()` function doesn't return until the dialog closes, so this will never trigger the step 3.

How can this be done?

**Edit**

These are the functions for notifying a task start and task end:

```
void CmodguiApp::_notify_task_start() {
  _processing_dialog->DoModal();
}

void CmodguiApp::_notify_task_end() {
  _processing_dialog->EndDialog(1);
}
```

This is the code triggering a task process:

```
void trigger_task(std::function<void()> f) {
  CmodguiApp::_notify_task_start();
  f();
  CmodguiApp::_notify_task_end();
}
```

Comment: Start a thread and do the processing there.

Comment: Run your task in a thread. You can start the thread in the `WM_INITDIALOG` handler to ensure the dialog handle will be available when the thread finishes and you want to close the dialog.

Comment: @MichaelWalz my processing is done inside a separate thread already, but CmodguiApp::_notify_task_start(); and CmodguiApp::_notify_task_end(); must be called in that thread

Comment: If you need your processing thread to communicate with the dialog then post messages to it, don't call the `_notifyXXX` functions directly.

Comment: well, if you want a modeless dialog, then you can't use the "DoModal" method, you need to Create it and then use ShowWindow. But the creation of the dialog must be synchronous because you need it to be already opened when you try to close it with "notify_task_end". The "_notify_task_end" can be asynchronous. Anyway, I think you don't need those separate methods, but you can declare the dialog directly inside the "trigger_task" method, so when the method ends its job, the dialog will go out of scope and so will be deleted and closed automatically

Comment: Make your dialog modal and start the thread in OnInitDialog.

Comment: @MichaelWalz yep that's what I ended up doing

Comment: @manatttta can you post the answer when you have it ready? it would be interesting to see

Comment: @manatttta: What about a TopMost Modal dialog?

Comment: for topmost: _processing_dialog->SetWindowPos(&_processing_dialog->wndTopMost, 0,0,0,0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach:

1. Call the

   `_processing_dialog->DoModal();`
2. On the Process dialog class do it wherever appropriate:

   `AfxGetApp()->GetMainWnd()->SendMessage(WM_YOUR_USER_MESSAGE)`
3. On the main window class message map, add

   `ON_MESSAGE(WM_YOUR_USER_MESSAGE, YourUserMessageHandlerFunction)`
4. Implement the `YourUserMessageHandlerFunction()`. Now you have retaken the handling at the main window.